# Как мне связать радио имеющие разных родителей?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, qbuttongroup

Мой код:

```
import sys
import os 

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 800)
        self.setStyleSheet('background:red;')



        wid = QWidget(self)
        wid.setStyleSheet('background:brown;')

        lay = QVBoxLayout(wid)

        self.rad = QRadioButton(wid)
        self.rad.setStyleSheet('background:blue;')
        lay.addWidget(self.rad)

        self.rad2 = QRadioButton(wid)
        self.rad2.setStyleSheet('background:blue;')
        lay.addWidget(self.rad2)


        wid2 = QWidget(self)
        wid2.setStyleSheet('background:green;')

        lay.addWidget(wid2)

        lay2 = QVBoxLayout(wid2)

        self.rad3 = QRadioButton(wid)
        self.rad3.setStyleSheet('background:green;')
        lay2.addWidget(self.rad3)


        self.rad4 = QRadioButton(wid)
        self.rad4.setStyleSheet('background:green;')
        lay2.addWidget(self.rad4)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я хочу связать между собой синие и зеленые радио.
Так как если бы они находились в одном виджете.
Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: надо объединить в одну `QButtonGroup`, но не уверен что с разными родителями будет работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать такие кнопки, как `QCheckBox`, `QRadioButton`, `QPushButton` и `QToolButton`, которые должны быть эксклюзивными, то вы должны использовать `QButtonGroup`:

```
import sys
#import os 
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(200, 200)
        self.setStyleSheet('background:red;')

        wid = QWidget(self)
        wid.setStyleSheet('background:brown;')

        lay = QVBoxLayout(wid)

        self.rad = QRadioButton(wid)
        self.rad.setStyleSheet('background:blue;')
        lay.addWidget(self.rad)

        self.rad2 = QRadioButton(wid)
        self.rad2.setStyleSheet('background:blue;')
        lay.addWidget(self.rad2)

        wid2 = QWidget(self)
        wid2.setStyleSheet('background:green;')

        lay.addWidget(wid2)

        lay2 = QVBoxLayout(wid2)

        self.rad3 = QRadioButton(wid)
        self.rad3.setStyleSheet('background:green;')
        lay2.addWidget(self.rad3)

        self.rad4 = QRadioButton(wid)
        self.rad4.setStyleSheet('background:green;')
        lay2.addWidget(self.rad4)

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        buttonGroup = QButtonGroup(self, exclusive=True)
        buttonGroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.onButtonClicked)   #(int id)
        buttonGroup.addButton(self.rad, 1)
        buttonGroup.addButton(self.rad2, 2)
        buttonGroup.addButton(self.rad3, 3)
        buttonGroup.addButton(self.rad4, 4)

    def onButtonClicked(self, id):
        print(id)
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]